# Model relationship - loopback ORM

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

How to connect models created in loopback and fetch the associated data?

configuration:

```
model1 *has many* model2
model2 *belongs to* model1
```

I did build `has many` using `slc loopback:relation` and the `model1` and `model2` are connected but failed to show the associated `model2` while displaying the `model1` contents.

Any suggestion? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown any code, but I suspect that you are not including `model2` in your query. You need to instruct LoopBack to include related models.

**Node.js**

```
model1.find({include: 'model2'}, function() { ... });
```

**REST**

```
model1?filter[include]=model2
```

https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Include+filter